# 10 bit to 8 bit image transfer with misc.save in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I got those raw image data with 10 bit values.

1. If I use misc.save to save it as 8 bit images, what happens to the values? does it automatically to scale or the values exceed 256 will be set to 256?
2. If I manually normalize the 10 bit data by dividing it by 2^10, then multiply those by 2^8. Finally, save the data as uint8 images, is this reasonable?

just by looking at the output images from method 1 and 2. Images from the second method appear darker comparing with those from method 1.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: you don't have to look at the output image. you're a programmer. look at the values...